# Error: Cast to undefined failed for value undefined at path "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am a beginner JavaScript developer.
I am getting this error when I try to get all soldiers by route: "localhost:3005/api/v1/soldiers" in POSTMAN.

I wrote schema for HomePost, services, controllers and routes and used  mongoose, express. When sending any requests, everything worked fine. Find by ID, delete by ID, create home post, get home posts list.
I started writing a similar schema, services, controllers and routes for soldiers.

```
models/sordier.model.js

import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Soldier = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rank: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }, 
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: '1'
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  }
})

export default mongoose.model('Soldier', Soldier)
```

```
services/soldiers.service.js

export const getSoldiers = async ({
  offset = 0,
  limit = 9
}) => Soldier.find({}, null, {
  skip: parseInt(offset),
  limit: parseInt(limit)
})
```

```
api/soldiers/soldiers.controller.js

export const SoldiersListController = async (request, response, next) => {

  try {
    const { offset, limit } = request.query
    
    const soldiers = await getSoldiers({
      offset,
      limit
    })

    return response
      .status(200)
      .json({
        status: true,
        soldiers: Array.isArray(soldiers) 
          ? soldiers?.map(soldier => SoldiersListItemMapper(soldier)) 
          : []
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error)
  }
  
  return response
    .status(200)
    .json({
      success: true,
      data
    })
}
```

```
api/soldiers/soldiers.mapper.js

export const SoldiersListItemMapper = soldier => ({
  id: soldier._id,
  title: soldier.title,
  image: soldier.image,
  rank: soldier.rank,
})
```

```
api/index.js

import { Router } from 'express'
import HomeRoute from './home'
import SoldiersRoute from './soldiers'

export default () => {
  const router = Router()

  HomeRoute(router)
  SoldiersRoute(router)
  
  return router
}
```

Using POSTMAN, I made sure that the function works:
create a soldier, get one by ID, delete one by ID, but getting a list of soldiers does not work.

I am catching the error:
Error: Cast to undefined failed for value undefined at path "undefined"

What can I do?

Comment: Hi, this is very well described! Can I ask you to elaborate a bit on "And at this stage I can't get request in the console". Where exactly is the error thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your responsiveness! 
In POSTMAN I send a GET request on the route: "http://localhost:3005/api/v1/soldiers"
Then I get the error that is written in the title of this post

Comment: Can you get a stack trace of the error? E.g. In your catch-clause, see if you can print the error to the console.

Comment: How are you sure the error comes from SoldiersListController?